# how to set width of td and div for different resolution using css

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a table and div. Based on the different screen resolutions (1920px, 1440px, 1536px) the div should get aligned with `<td>`. I tried media queries for `<td>` and `<div>` which is not working. Any help and suggestion on how to make this work would be of great help to me.

```css
table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #00cf45;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1440px) {
  .div2 {
    width: 10%;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1440px) {
  .div2 {
    width: 9%;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1440px) {
  .div3 {
    width: 10%;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="">
  <div class="div1" style="width:150px;display:inline-flex;"><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Text"> </div>
  <div class="div2" style="width:120px;display:inline-flex;">
    <select style="width:120px;" id="cars" name="cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="div3" style="width:120px;display:inline-flex;"><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Text"> </div>
  <div class="div4" style="width:150px;display:inline-flex;">
    <select style="width:120px;" id="cars" name="cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="div5" style="width:150px;display:inline-flex;"><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Text"> </div>
</div>
<table>

  <tr>
    <td style="width:15%">
      Width of this column remains same on varying screen-size
    </td>
    <td style="width:10%">
      Width of this column changes on varying screen-size
    </td>
    <td style="width:9%">
      Width of this column also changes on varying screen-size
    </td>
    <td style="width:10%">
      Width of this column also changes on varying screen-size
    </td>
    <td style="width:56%">
      Width of this column also changes on varying screen-size
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:15%">
      Width of this column remains same on varying screen-size
    </td>
    <td style="width:10%">
      Width of this column changes on varying screen-size
    </td>
    <td style="width:9%">
      Width of this column also changes on varying screen-size
    </td>
    <td style="width:10%">
      Width of this column also changes on varying screen-size
    </td>
    <td style="width:56%">
      Width of this column also changes on varying screen-size
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:15%">
      Width of this column remains same on varying screen-size
    </td>
    <td style="width:10%">
      Width of this column changes on varying screen-size
    </td>
    <td style="width:9%">
      Width of this column also changes on varying screen-size
    </td>
    <td style="width:10%">
      Width of this column also changes on varying screen-size
    </td>
    <td style="width:56%">
      Width of this column also changes on varying screen-size
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:15%">
      Width of this column remains same on varying screen-size
    </td>
    <td style="width:10%">
      Width of this column changes on varying screen-size
    </td>
    <td style="width:9%">
      Width of this column also changes on varying screen-size
    </td>
    <td style="width:10%">
      Width of this column also changes on varying screen-size
    </td>
    <td style="width:56%">
      Width of this column also changes on varying screen-size
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

here is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/y2v1waso/

Comment: more details for be helpfull. What exactly is not workign as intended? what should the desire behavior be? `I tried something but it isnt working` is a quite useless statement. Nobody knows what you actually intend to do. Also there is no reason to create a new media querry with the same rules for different elements. wrap all different selectors within the same media query. Best add a drawing of what you itnend to do. Unelss you want to display data, a table is the wrong tool to choose anyways. Its not for styling purpose, for that you either have flexbox or better yet css-grid.

Comment: what I want is, when I resize the window, the input fields (div)on top of the table should get aligned with the respective td. which is not getting aligned when I resize the window now. I cannot explain that with a drwaing